# Drop TSQL temp tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports, temp-tables

In the report Command, I use this code before populating a temp table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GROUPERS') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #GROUPERS;
    END;
```

When I save and run the command, I get this error message:

[image: SAP Crystal Reports error creating and dropping temp table]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: check for errors before the if statement.

Comment: I am suspicious of the fact that in the error message the keyword "if" is in lowercase and in your SQL it is in Uppercase.  Perhaps our princess is in another castle.

Comment: @JayWheeler the princess is in the same castle. The change in casing is due to editing of the question

Comment: @KamranFarzami is almost certainly correct here. Remove this block of code and run what ever is above it... you should get a new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking out all the CTEs in the code helped. Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

When I run this I get 'It does not exist

```
create table #GROUPERS(i1 int)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GROUPERS') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #GROUPERS;
    END;

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GROUPERS') IS NOT NULL
    print 'It exists'
else
    print 'It does not exist'
```

This means that the logic works. I am willing to bet that there is a unprintable character (invisible character) on the line where the if statement is. Did you cut and paste this code from somewhere? Try clicking on the error message. It may take you to where the error is. There may be strange characters at the end of the line....